# File.exists() working in localhost but not in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, iis-7.5

I have a code in c#(asp.net) in which File.exists() returns a false value when I execute it in IIS 7.5 but returns a true value when I run it in my localhost via visual studio debugging.

I've checked all the read and write permissions and all IIS users have all the permissions for the folder.

Can anyone suggest any way to fix this?

Attached is the code for reference:-

```
protected void downloadFiles(string nric)
{
    string serverPath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Temp\");
    string folderName = nric;
    string dirName = serverPath + folderName;
    string logFilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Temp\");
    string logFile = logFilePath + "log2.txt";
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(logFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    StreamWriter logWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);//File.CreateText(logFile);
    logWriter.WriteLine("Preparing to export  ....." + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    try
    {
        logWriter.WriteLine("entered try loop");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName + "\\CollectionsItems");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dh.Fill("ACP", dt, "P_ACP_COLLECTION_VIEW_SEARCH_OWN", nric, "", "", "");
        foreach (DataRow dRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            logWriter.WriteLine("entered for loop");
            string fileURL = dRow["FILE_URL"].ToString();
            logWriter.WriteLine("file URL =" + fileURL);
            string collectionFolder = dRow["COLLECTION_FOLDER"].ToString();
            string collectionFile = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("root") + "\\" + nric + "\\" + collectionFolder, fileURL);
            //string orgFile = collectionFile.Replace("\\", "/");
            string orgFile = collectionFile;
            string filName = dirName + "\\CollectionsItems\\" + fileURL;
            logWriter.WriteLine("org file =" + orgFile);
            logWriter.WriteLine("file name =" + filName);
            //WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            //wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(orgFile), filName);
            if (File.Exists(orgFile))
            {
                logWriter.WriteLine("entered if loop");
                FileStream readStream = new FileStream(orgFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(filName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                ReadWriteStream(readStream, writeStream);
                //File.Copy(orgFile,filName,true);
            }
        }

        logWriter.WriteLine(" ");
        logWriter.WriteLine("Exporting Completed  ....." + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        logWriter.Flush();
        logWriter.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Following are the log files generated in local host and IIS.

localhost:-
Preparing to export  .....4/30/2013 5:03:46 PM
entered try loop
entered for loop
file URL =CO201304262025117208.jpg
org file =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imprints3\Temp\demostu01\Achievements\CO201304262025117208.jpg
file name =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Cybersphere_imprints\Temp\demostu01\CollectionsItems\CO201304262025117208.jpg
entered if loop
entered for loop
file URL =CO201304231616496601.jpg
org file =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imprints3\Temp\demostu01\Achievements\CO201304231616496601.jpg
file name =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Cybersphere_imprints\Temp\demostu01\CollectionsItems\CO201304231616496601.jpg
entered if loop
entered for loop
file URL =CO201303281418567609.docx
org file =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imprints3\Temp\demostu01\Achievements\CO201303281418567609.docx
file name =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Cybersphere_imprints\Temp\demostu01\CollectionsItems\CO201303281418567609.docx

Exporting Completed  .....4/30/2013 5:03:46 PM

IIS:-
Preparing to export  .....4/30/2013 5:05:57 PM
entered try loop
entered for loop
file URL =CO201304262025117208.jpg
org file =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imprints3\Temp\demostu01\Achievements\CO201304262025117208.jpg
file name =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imprints3\Temp\demostu01\CollectionsItems\CO201304262025117208.jpg
entered for loop
file URL =CO201304231616496601.jpg
org file =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imprints3\Temp\demostu01\Achievements\CO201304231616496601.jpg
file name =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imprints3\Temp\demostu01\CollectionsItems\CO201304231616496601.jpg
entered for loop
file URL =CO201303281418567609.docx
org file =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imprints3\Temp\demostu01\Achievements\CO201303281418567609.docx
file name =C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imprints3\Temp\demostu01\CollectionsItems\CO201303281418567609.docx

Exporting Completed  .....4/30/2013 5:05:57 PM

As it can be seen, the difference in log files is that they are not entering the if loop which is weird as the files exist and the same function is entering the if loop in my localhost.

Comment: i think problem is in "string collectionFile = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("root") + "\\" + nric + "\\" + collectionFolder, fileURL);" this line.Check for your root value.need to use Server.MapPath

Comment: dh.Fill should probably be dt.Fill. Typo?

Comment: yes it must be dt instead of dh.

Comment: dh is the data handler i had declared in the class so it should be okay.

Comment: OK, then it could be a permission problem. Application pool identity may not be authorized to read contents of the directory.

Comment: For Temp folder(in which everything is stored), I've given all permissions to IIS USERS and USERS. the application pool identity for my application pool is set to localsystem. Do I need to give any more permissions anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) :

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(orgFile))
```

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) for path related information.

Comment: Tried this but this also doesn't work. My log file also doesn't get generated after making this change so I'm assuming logwriter doesn't get flushed and closed. One question though. If I'm passing physical path into the script directly, why do I need to use Server.MapPath?

Comment: you can check the url for more info

Comment: In the url, they are passing the virtual path to find the physical path, right? In my case, I already know the physical path as can be seen from the log files.